# What does this command mean: awk -F'/BaseCalls/' '{print $2}'?

Tags: command-line, awk

Please explain what does this command mean?

```
awk -F'/BaseCalls/' '{print $2}'
```

I know -F tells awk to use(colon) as field separator.
and '{print $2}' means print the second field (the fields being separated by :)

Is it trying to read the filenames in the /Basecalls/directory  or process the files and read data present inside the files in the /Basecalls/ directory.

Answer (score 2):

It says print the second column while the delimiter (field separator) is: `'/BaseCalls/'`.

- `-F` means field separator, what is going to separate my fields? is it a colon? is it a "x" character or something else? and here we are telling `awk` that the string `"/BaseCalls/"` is our field separator.

In a file with a content similar to:

```
foo/BaseCalls/bar
zee/BaseCalls/baz
```

it will print:

```
bar
baz
```

If I use it like `awk -F:`, now it means that my field separator is a colon, which will be used on a data like:

```
foo:bar
zee:baz
```